# Activating a non-pinnable library in rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

A rails 7.0.7 application aims to implement an autocomplete feature for a form field.

Unfortunately, the library referenced below cannot be pinned

```
./bin/importmap pin JavaScript-autoComplete
Couldn't find any packages in ["JavaScript-autoComplete"] on jspm
```

Thus, the plain JS library has to be integrated manually.  The following step is to integrate it in a rails view and call it for the various necessities. At 10k size, the price is acceptable.  The content is at the end of this posting.

However, as presently cast the:
`<%= javascript_tag do %> var item1 = new autoComplete({` 
fails upon page load. The console indicates :
`Uncaught ReferenceError: autoComplete is not defined`
thus it appears the js variable definition `var autoComplete` is not seen by the javascript_tag object

How can this be properly run?

```
<%= form_with model: @individual, data: {turbo: false} do |form| %>
  [...]
  <%= form.text_field :tz %>
  [...]
<% end %>

<script>
// JavaScript autoComplete v1.0.4
// https://github.com/Pixabay/JavaScript-autoComplete
/*
    JavaScript autoComplete v1.0.4
    Copyright (c) 2014 Simon Steinberger / Pixabay
    GitHub: https://github.com/Pixabay/JavaScript-autoComplete
    License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

var autoComplete = (function(){
    // "use strict";
    function autoComplete(options){
        if (!document.querySelector) return;

        // helpers
        function hasClass(el, className){ return el.classList ? el.classList.contains(className) : new RegExp('\\b'+ className+'\\b').test(el.className); }

        function addEvent(el, type, handler){
            if (el.attachEvent) el.attachEvent('on'+type, handler); else el.addEventListener(type, handler);
        }
        function removeEvent(el, type, handler){
            // if (el.removeEventListener) not working in IE11
            if (el.detachEvent) el.detachEvent('on'+type, handler); else el.removeEventListener(type, handler);
        }
        function live(elClass, event, cb, context){
            addEvent(context || document, event, function(e){
                var found, el = e.target || e.srcElement;
                while (el && !(found = hasClass(el, elClass))) el = el.parentElement;
                if (found) cb.call(el, e);
            });
        }

        var o = {
            selector: 0,
            source: 0,
            minChars: 3,
            delay: 150,
            offsetLeft: 0,
            offsetTop: 1,
            cache: 1,
            menuClass: '',
            renderItem: function (item, search){
                // escape special characters
                search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
                var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
                return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
            },
            onSelect: function(e, term, item){}
        };
        for (var k in options) { if (options.hasOwnProperty(k)) o[k] = options[k]; }

        // init
        var elems = typeof o.selector == 'object' ? [o.selector] : document.querySelectorAll(o.selector);
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            var that = elems[i];

            // create suggestions container "sc"
            that.sc = document.createElement('div');
            that.sc.className = 'autocomplete-suggestions '+o.menuClass;

            that.autocompleteAttr = that.getAttribute('autocomplete');
            that.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
            that.cache = {};
            that.last_val = '';

            that.updateSC = function(resize, next){
                var rect = that.getBoundingClientRect();
                that.sc.style.left = Math.round(rect.left + (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft) + o.offsetLeft) + 'px';
                that.sc.style.top = Math.round(rect.bottom + (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) + o.offsetTop) + 'px';
                that.sc.style.width = Math.round(rect.right - rect.left) + 'px'; // outerWidth
                if (!resize) {
                    that.sc.style.display = 'block';
                    if (!that.sc.maxHeight) { that.sc.maxHeight = parseInt((window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(that.sc, null) : that.sc.currentStyle).maxHeight); }
                    if (!that.sc.suggestionHeight) that.sc.suggestionHeight = that.sc.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestion').offsetHeight;
                    if (that.sc.suggestionHeight)
                        if (!next) that.sc.scrollTop = 0;
                        else {
                            var scrTop = that.sc.scrollTop, selTop = next.getBoundingClientRect().top - that.sc.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                            if (selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight - that.sc.maxHeight > 0)
                                that.sc.scrollTop = selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight + scrTop - that.sc.maxHeight;
                            else if (selTop < 0)
                                that.sc.scrollTop = selTop + scrTop;
                        }
                }
            }
            addEvent(window, 'resize', that.updateSC);
            document.body.appendChild(that.sc);

            live('autocomplete-suggestion', 'mouseleave', function(e){
                var sel = that.sc.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected');
                if (sel) setTimeout(function(){ sel.className = sel.className.replace('selected', ''); }, 20);
            }, that.sc);

            live('autocomplete-suggestion', 'mouseover', function(e){
                var sel = that.sc.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected');
                if (sel) sel.className = sel.className.replace('selected', '');
                this.className += ' selected';
            }, that.sc);

            live('autocomplete-suggestion', 'mousedown', function(e){
                if (hasClass(this, 'autocomplete-suggestion')) { // else outside click
                    var v = this.getAttribute('data-val');
                    that.value = v;
                    o.onSelect(e, v, this);
                    that.sc.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }, that.sc);

            that.blurHandler = function(){
                try { var over_sb = document.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestions:hover'); } catch(e){ var over_sb = 0; }
                if (!over_sb) {
                    that.last_val = that.value;
                    that.sc.style.display = 'none';
                    setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.style.display = 'none'; }, 350); // hide suggestions on fast input
                } else if (that !== document.activeElement) setTimeout(function(){ that.focus(); }, 20);
            };
            addEvent(that, 'blur', that.blurHandler);

            var suggest = function(data){
                var val = that.value;
                that.cache[val] = data;
                if (data.length && val.length >= o.minChars) {
                    var s = '';
                    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) s += o.renderItem(data[i], val);
                    that.sc.innerHTML = s;
                    that.updateSC(0);
                }
                else
                    that.sc.style.display = 'none';
            }

            that.keydownHandler = function(e){
                var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                // down (40), up (38)
                if ((key == 40 || key == 38) && that.sc.innerHTML) {
                    var next, sel = that.sc.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected');
                    if (!sel) {
                        next = (key == 40) ? that.sc.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestion') : that.sc.childNodes[that.sc.childNodes.length - 1]; // first : last
                        next.className += ' selected';
                        that.value = next.getAttribute('data-val');
                    } else {
                        next = (key == 40) ? sel.nextSibling : sel.previousSibling;
                        if (next) {
                            sel.className = sel.className.replace('selected', '');
                            next.className += ' selected';
                            that.value = next.getAttribute('data-val');
                        }
                        else { sel.className = sel.className.replace('selected', ''); that.value = that.last_val; next = 0; }
                    }
                    that.updateSC(0, next);
                    return false;
                }
                // esc
                else if (key == 27) { that.value = that.last_val; that.sc.style.display = 'none'; }
                // enter
                else if (key == 13 || key == 9) {
                    var sel = that.sc.querySelector('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected');
                    if (sel && that.sc.style.display != 'none') { o.onSelect(e, sel.getAttribute('data-val'), sel); setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.style.display = 'none'; }, 20); }
                }
            };
            addEvent(that, 'keydown', that.keydownHandler);

            that.keyupHandler = function(e){
                var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                if (!key || (key < 35 || key > 40) && key != 13 && key != 27) {
                    var val = that.value;
                    if (val.length >= o.minChars) {
                        if (val != that.last_val) {
                            that.last_val = val;
                            clearTimeout(that.timer);
                            if (o.cache) {
                                if (val in that.cache) { suggest(that.cache[val]); return; }
                                // no requests if previous suggestions were empty
                                for (var i=1; i<val.length-o.minChars; i++) {
                                    var part = val.slice(0, val.length-i);
                                    if (part in that.cache && !that.cache[part].length) { suggest([]); return; }
                                }
                            }
                            that.timer = setTimeout(function(){ o.source(val, suggest) }, o.delay);
                        }
                    } else {
                        that.last_val = val;
                        that.sc.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            };
            addEvent(that, 'keyup', that.keyupHandler);

            that.focusHandler = function(e){
                that.last_val = '\n';
                that.keyupHandler(e)
            };
            if (!o.minChars) addEvent(that, 'focus', that.focusHandler);
        }

        // public destroy method
        this.destroy = function(){
            for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
                var that = elems[i];
                removeEvent(window, 'resize', that.updateSC);
                removeEvent(that, 'blur', that.blurHandler);
                removeEvent(that, 'focus', that.focusHandler);
                removeEvent(that, 'keydown', that.keydownHandler);
                removeEvent(that, 'keyup', that.keyupHandler);
                if (that.autocompleteAttr)
                    that.setAttribute('autocomplete', that.autocompleteAttr);
                else
                    that.removeAttribute('autocomplete');
                document.body.removeChild(that.sc);
                that = null;
            }
        };
    }
    return autoComplete;
})();

(function(){
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define('autoComplete', function () { return autoComplete; });
    else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)
        module.exports = autoComplete;
    else
        window.autoComplete = autoComplete;
})();
</script>


<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var item1 = new autoComplete({
      selector: '#individual_tz',
      minChars: 2,
      source: function(term, suggest){
          term = term.toLowerCase();
          var choices = <%= raw @timezone_names %>;
          var suggestions = [];
          for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
              if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
          suggest(suggestions);
      }
  });
<% end %>
```

Comment: you mean like this? `bin/importmap pin javascript-autocomplete`

Comment: the capitalization of libraries is a wet bar of soap to me.  The ReadMe calls it "JavaScript-autoComplete".  Your syntax does load version 1.0.5 when the github repo has 1.0.4 showing... `https://ga.jspm.io/npm:javascript-autocomplete@1.0.5/auto-complete.js`   Needs parsing to double-check it is the right one!

Comment: you can just search for it on npm which returns nothing unless lowercased https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-autocomplete also you can search for it on jspm when it doesn't work from the console https://generator.jspm.io/ you can also pin from other cdns like jsdelivr

Comment: that script now loads in the header of the document `"javascript-autocomplete": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:javascript-autocomplete@1.0.5/auto-complete.js",`  but the browser console still returns ` autoComplete is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost feel like we've done this one before. Once you pin a package you have to import it, no exceptions. Pins are a rails way to construct an importmap, then you make use of that importmap with `import`s.

Because we working with modules you do not get a global `autoComplete` which you can see from this part of the code:

```js
(function(){
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define('autoComplete', function () { return autoComplete; });
    else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)
        // NOTE: modules get a default export
        module.exports = autoComplete;
    else
        // NOTE: regular scripts get a global
        window.autoComplete = autoComplete;
})();
```

So

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import autoComplete from "javascript-autocomplete" // jspm does ES modules only

// make it global if needed
window.autoComplete = autoComplete
```

---

If you really need a global, you can get even more confused by pinning this library from jsdelivr:

```bash
bin/importmap pin javascript-autocomplete --from jsdelivr
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "javascript-autocomplete" // this package is not an ES module

// already global
console.log(autoComplete)
```

I just know this works, actual details are quite fuzzy for me.

---

**Update**

Just to finish answering your question. I'm using jsdelivr pin, since using a module doesn't really have any benefit here.

```
<%= form_with url: request.path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :tz %>
<% end %>

<script type="module">
  var choices = ['pst', 'mnt', 'est'];
  var item1 = new autoComplete({
      selector: '#tz',
      minChars: 2,
      source: function(term, suggest){
          var suggestions = [];
          choices.forEach(tz => {
            if (tz.startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) {
              suggestions.push(tz);
            }
          })
          suggest(suggestions);
      }
  });
</script>
```

Works on reload, on turbo navigation and back and with a cached preview.

Typing "ps" or "mn" or "es" shows a suggestion:

[image: autocomplete screenshot]

Comment: @Jerome one more issue with what you're doing: you're adding an event listener every time you visit that page - those listeners are sticking around and accumulating, and will run on other pages as well. because with Turbo, pages are not refreshed between visits. for inspection there is an "Event Listeners" tab next to "Styles".

Comment: Only the repo as is (sorry, my gitignore file was misconfigured until now) runs, github.com/dvodvo/tz  but on page reload only.  What I am certain of is it has to do with turbo.  i.e. load vs `turbolinks:load`... And as i type this, I realise the syntax evolved, my memory **not** ... yep 'turbo:load'  in the EventListener allows execution on first load.

Comment: @Jerome i ran your repo, it is "working" after adding "database.yml" and "development.rb" environment. have you tried: `for (let i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {`, I assume you have `@timezone_names` initialized with something. and it works fine with `<script type="module">` and no event listeners. (sorry, I don't mean to keep pestering you about this, just trying to save you a headache later on).

Comment: Yes, database.yml is under `gitignore`  and the application controller defines the instance variable.  Pestering? no, no... this is helping immensely!

Answer (score 0):

Pity, @Greg had the proper thought:  ensure the document is fully loaded.
loaded the library with `bin/importmap pin javascript-autocomplete`  and
`application.js`  appended with

```
import autoComplete from "javascript-autocomplete"

window.autoComplete = autoComplete
```

Wrapping the existing code as below triggers expected behaviour

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.addEventListener('turbo:load', function () {
    var item1 = new autoComplete({
        selector: '#individual_tz',
        minChars: 2,
        source: function(term, suggest){
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            var choices = <%= raw @timezone_names %>;
            var suggestions = [];
            for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
            suggest(suggestions);
        }
    });
  })
<% end %>
```

**update**

the EventListener would fire only on page reload with
`window.addEventListener('load', function () {`
turbo needs to be taken into account.
`window.addEventListener('turbo:load', function () {`

*with the introduction of turbo the syntax is 'turbo'  when previously it was 'turbolinks'*

Comment: probably, better put it in a `<script type="module">` instead of adding an event listener.

Comment: Did not succeed in doing that.  Discovered something additional in the repo https://github.com/dvodvo/tz  - on first pageload, the js does not trigger; on reload it does...